# Why sql is loading data infinite?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables for statistics events, and sessions, here is how they look

**Here Sessions Table  Showing rows 0 - 29 (4 730 018 total))**

[image]

**And here is events table  Showing rows 0 - 29 (3686 total)**

[image]

Now here is data I am displaying 
[image]

Now here is my SQL for displaying data

```
SELECT sessions.sid, 
       events.datetime, 
       count(*) as num_rows, 
       count(distinct sessions.sid) as sessions, 
    sum( targetbuttonname = 'kredyt' ) as num_kredyt, 
    sum( targetbuttonname = 'konto' ) as num_konto,
    sum( targetbuttonname = 'czat' ) as num_czat,
    sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-voice_btns' ) as num_voice,
    sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-close_btn' )  as num_close,
    sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-muted_btn' ) as num_muted,
    sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-play_btn' )  as num_play,
    sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-pause_btn' )  as num_pause,
    sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-replay_btn' ) as num_replay, 
    sum(watchtime) as num_watchtime, 
    sum(devicetype ='Computer') as num_computer 
from events INNER JOIN
     sessions
     ON events.sid =sessions.sid;
```

> Now when I have small data everything works fine

Now when I have huge data in a sessions table as you can see above over 4 million data,

And try to run the script above in my PHPmyadmin the request never ends and MariaDB doesn't respond anymore, I have to restart the service manually.

What do I need to do to solve my problem?

Comment: does it run from a non-web client such as Sequel Pro, Heidi SQL, or navicat? It could be Apache/NginX timing out whilst the db is still busy chuntering away

Comment: Shouldn't your results be grouped by something?

Comment: @delboy1978uk no, It runs through amazon aws,

Comment: that shouldnt matter, you should be able to connect with any client over ssh

Comment: Have a look here https://ehikioya.com/amazon-rds-heidisql-ssh-tunneling/

Comment: do you have any other client? Which OS are you on?

Comment: am using windows 10

Comment: Also, have you indexed your tables properly?

Comment: No am not good at database what does indexing Mya table can help to solve my problem?

Comment: You use impilcit GROUP BY and calculate the result over all dataset obtaining ONE final row. But you select `sessions.sid` and `events.datetime` which are not arguments of any aggregate function. So you'll either get error message or obtain some random value from all possible values. Do you really need this? Do you need in these fields at all? And do you need in `count(*) as num_rows` which is really a sum of `(COUNT(events.*) * COUNT(sessions.*))` for each separate `sid`? this value can tell nothing in practice.

Comment: Judging from your photos, `sid` in `events` table won't be unique.. (obviously), how about `sessions` table? Will the `sid` be unique?

Comment: Yes, indexing can help partially same with types and settings. Include `SHOW CREATE TABLE sessions`; `SHOW CREATE TABLE events`; `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer_size'` and `EXPLAIN {the query}` in your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect the problem is the `count(distinct)`.  I also see no use in bringing in `sid` or `datetime`.

Does this do what you want

```
 select count(*) as num_rows,
        (select count(*) from sessions) as sessions,
        sum( targetbuttonname = 'kredyt' ) as num_kredyt, 
        sum( targetbuttonname = 'konto' ) as num_konto,
        sum( targetbuttonname = 'czat' ) as num_czat,
        sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-voice_btns' ) as num_voice,
        sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-close_btn' )  as num_close,
        sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-muted_btn' ) as num_muted,
        sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-play_btn' )  as num_play,
        sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-pause_btn' )  as num_pause,
        sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-replay_btn' ) as num_replay, 
        sum(watchtime) as num_watchtime, 
        sum(devicetype ='Computer') as num_computer 
 from events e ;
```

Comment: I am getting the following error : ` #1054 - Unknown column 's.sid' in 'field list'`

Comment: @user9964622 . . . Ooops.  That expression should have been deleted.

Comment: What about session table?  Why did you remove join? Remember sessions.sid comes from session's table, inshort ur answer does not work, return's sessions.sid undefined :(

Comment: @user9964622 . . . Your original query should be getting a syntax error for including that column (as happily it would in the more recent versions of MySQL).  The count is calculated by the subquery.

Comment: The unique difference between this query result and the original is that Sessions without events would be counted too (but probably It doesn't exists or It is expected to be counted)

Comment: I agree that probably this query is what he needs. but still would suggest to him to verify If the foreignkey is created and If the fields is well indexed.

Comment: @Frederic ur right I just needed the tables to be indexed properly, now everything works as expected

Answer (score 1):

Since you said **it works when there’s small amount of data**, issue could be time out (fetching or transferring) data. Try limiting no of rows you get. You can use “limit by” to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to modify the configuration file of `phpMyAdmin` or `Apache` or `Nginx`. Actually, you should use the terminal to do statistics.

By the way, you should make sure the configurations are correct:

1. MySQL's `max_execution_time`, just execute this SQL: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%max_execution_time%'`
2. Nginx: add `keepalive_timeout 60s;` to your nginx.conf
3. PHP: modify max_execution_time value in php.ini
4. phpMyAdmin: you can see [this](https://www.e2enetworks.com/help/knowledge-base/increase-timeout-session-in-phpmyadmin/) article

There are too many places that cause timeouts.